# Change lock screen shortcut?

Tags: release-freya, release-loki, keyboard-shortcuts

How do I change the logout shortcut?

Currently it is set to `CMD + L`. I cannot find such setting in Settings->Keyboard->Shortcuts.

It is terribly inconvenient  for me as I switch frequently from OSX to elementaryOS.

Also, setting this does not work:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Change shortcut

To change the shortcut to (for example) <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> run the following in a terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screensaver "<Super><Ctrl>l"
```

## Disable screensaver

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screensaver "[]"
```

No more accidental locks when trying to hit Chrome's omnibar! ;)

## Restore default shortcut

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screensaver
```