# Lock Screen shortcut setup

Tags: display, lock

Is there a keyboard shortcut that can be used to manually lock the screen? If not, can it be configured somehow?
Any pointer to relevant documentation would help.
Thanks,
Arjuna

Comment: This might be helpful: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7252/change-lock-screen-shortcut

Answer (score 2):

Super+L   (Super is the 'Windows' like key on your keyboard)

Comment: thanks, unfortunately I use Awesome Window Manager and the Windows key is remapped as Mod key and I believe this overrides any system shortcuts on that key.